# Magento C# RestApi call freezes my app

Tags: c#, rest, magento

I am trying to use Magento C# RestApi library to connect to my Magento Store.
I succeed to connect to it, then I want to get a product by it's SKU. I chose to look for an existing SKU, and I wrote this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new MagentoApi()
        .SetCustomAdminUrlPart("index.php/admin")
        .Initialize("http://www.example.com/magento/",
                    "57348583384fh8h83h4334h34", "8vh388hhfh487f34h8hiuw3")
        .AuthenticateAdmin("admin", "adminpassword");
    textBox1.AppendText("Connection successfull \n");
    Application.DoEvents();
    textBox1.AppendText("Looking for product with sku:" + "convertor-touchscreen \n");
    Application.DoEvents();
    var response = client.GetProductBySku("convertor-touchscreen").Result;
    textBox1.AppendText("Done locating product \n");
    Application.DoEvents();
    ...
}
```

- At first I ran my app, and it froze right after displaying the "Looking for product with sku..."
- Then, I started Fiddler to see what is happening, and surprise, my request returns a valid response... I expect my app to add a new line to my textBox... but my app chooses to freeze.

My textBox contains this before it freezes:

> Connection successfull Looking for product with
>   sku:convertor-touchscreen

Why does the response never come back to my app?

So here is what I receive (as per Fiddler) in TextView:

```
{
    "10": {
        "entity_id": "10",
        "attribute_set_id": "4",
        "type_id": "simple",
        "sku": "convertor-touchscreen",
        "name": "Convertor touchscreen",
        "meta_title": null,
        "meta_description": null,
        "url_key": "convertor-touchscreen",
        "custom_design": null,
        "page_layout": null,
        "options_container": "container1",
        "country_of_manufacture": null,
        "msrp_enabled": "2",
        "msrp_display_actual_price_type": "4",
        "gift_message_available": null,
        "creareseo_discontinued": null,
        "creareseo_discontinued_product": null,
        "description": "Convertor touchscreen",
        "short_description": "Convertor touchscreen",
        "meta_keyword": null,
        "custom_layout_update": null,
        "price": "421.0000",
        "special_price": "380.0000",
        "weight": "0.1500",
        "msrp": null,
        "special_from_date": "2015-11-24 00:00:00",
        "special_to_date": "2015-11-26 00:00:00",
        "news_from_date": null,
        "news_to_date": null,
        "custom_design_from": null,
        "custom_design_to": null,
        "status": "1",
        "visibility": "4",
        "tax_class_id": "2",
        "featured": "1"
    }
}
```

So **there is a response**

Why does this freeze my app? How can I get past this so I can get to interpreting it somehow?

I want to be able to access the attributes of the product from the JSON that appears to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is freezing because this:

```
var response = client.GetProductBySku("convertor-touchscreen").Result;
```

Is causing your code to deadlock. [You're blocking on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Instead, asynchronously wait on the asynchronous method using `await`:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new MagentoApi()
        .SetCustomAdminUrlPart("index.php/admin")
        .Initialize("http://www.example.com/magento/",
                    "57348583384fh8h83h4334h34", "8vh388hhfh487f34h8hiuw3")
        .AuthenticateAdmin("admin", "adminpassword");

    textBox1.AppendText("Connection successfull \n");
    textBox1.AppendText("Looking for product with sku:" + "convertor-touchscreen \n");
    var response = await client.GetProductBySku("convertor-touchscreen");
    textBox1.AppendText("Done locating product \n");
}
```

**Side note:**

There's really no reason to use [`Application.DoEvents`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents) here.

Comment: "Await operator can only be used within an Async method"

Comment: @user1137313 Did you mark your method with `async` modifier, as I did in my answer?

Comment: Thanks a million. I just wasted a night time sleep on this :(

Comment: @user1137313 You welcome. Those sleepless nights are what helps us learn and advance :)